# Does a tree pointer variable change in some other function?

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I've tested the below C++ code. It seems the root does not change. But shouldn't the root have changed in func from node with 3 to node with 5?

```
void func(BSTreeNode* root){
    root=root->right;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    BSTreeNode* root=new BSTreeNode(3);
    root->right=new BSTreeNode(5);
    func(root);
    cout<<root->val;
    return 0;
```

}

Besides, I've always wondered what is the difference between

```
TreeNode root=NULL;
```

and

```
TreeNode root;
```

Is it the first one actually be allocated with new memory and the second one not?

Comment: Arguments are passed by value in C. Changing the variable in the function doesn't affect the caller's variable.

Comment: `func` changes a local variable. This change is not visible to the caller. It's effectively a no-op - it's fully equivalent to `void func(BSTreeNode* root) {}`

Comment: As to your second question - difficult to answer precisely without knowing what `TreeNode` actually is.

Comment: `TreeNode root` declares the variable and initializes it to `NULL`. `TreeNode root` just declares the variable, but doesn't give it an initial value.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your function `func` updates a local variable. The assignment is not relected on the `root` variable declared in main.
2. In the first case, root is initialized to null. In the second case, root is not initialized and points to some unknown memory, likely to be invalid.